# Python error - List index out of range. Other fixes don't seem to work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that is checking how many vowels are in a string, but whenever I run it, I get a `list index out of range` error. I've looked around and seen that the usual fix was to do `range(len())` but I was already doing that. What do I do?

```
def count_vowels(message):
  new_message = message.lower()
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  x = 1
  for char in range(len(new_message)):
    output = new_message.count(vowels[x])
    x += 1    
  return output
```

Comment: Indexing in Python (and in all other good languages) starts from 0, not from 1. So, `x=0`. But even after this change, your code is still wrong: the number of iterations must be `len(vowels)`, not `len(new_message)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing a bunch of errors that I mentioned in the comment, your code could look like this:

```
def count_vowels(message):
  message = message.lower()
  vowels = 'aeiou'
  output = 0
  for char in vowels:
    output += message.count(char)
  return output
```

However, you are going through the string 5 times by calling `count` for each vowel. Instead, you can go through the message once and record all vowels as you see them:

```
def count_vowels(message):
  message = message.lower()
  vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'}
  output = 0
  for char in message:
    if char in vowels:
      output += 1
  return output
```

The latter can be made more compact by using a generator expression and the library function `sum`, because `char in vowels` is `True` (1) for vowels and `False` (0) for everything else:

```
def count_vowels(message):
  vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'}
  return sum((char in vowels) for char in message.lower())
```